# How to execute .sql using sh(bash) scripts similar to sqlcmd in .bat file

Tags: sql, sql-server, bash

Could anyone please provide me code snippet how to execute .sql file using sh(bash) commands similar to usage of sqlcmd in bat file

for example:
in Windows we have TestDB.bat file which will execute a command as below to run a Mytest.sql file against the specific DB under a server

**For Windows authentication:**

```
sqlcmd -b -S MyTestSQLServer -d MyDB -E  -I -i Mytest.sql
```

**For SQL authentication:**

```
sqlcmd -b -S MyTestSQLServer -d MyDB -U MyUser -P MyPassword  -I -i Mytest.sql
```

Comment: There's no difference. `sqlcmd` works the same in powershell and bash. The *only* differences I'm aware of is that `sqlcmd` on Linux doesn't support the `-v` switch, and thatjust running the command `sqlcmd` on Windows will try to connect to the localhost, using a trusted connection, but on Linux it will display the help dialogue (which would be `sqlcmd -?` on  Windows). *There may be a couple of other switch differences, but `-v` is the only one where I've noticed it doesn't exist when I've tried to use it.*

Comment: Obviously, however, you can't use a trusted connection in bash **unless** you have configured kerboros on your Linux environment (which isn't a trivial task).